# Flash stop receiving keyboards after Drag'n Drop, until I click the Flash again, or use Tab key... Weird problem

Tags: javascript, flash, events, keyboard, focus

I have a puzzling problem with Flash.

Coding a game, like so many others. Javascript and Flash both listen to keyboard events. 
Javascript redirects keys to Flash, like many others seem to do. It's working fine.

Then I created an inventory and items. Icons that can be dragged and dropped.

But if I drag and drop an item, suddenly, the keyboard events stop being triggered until I click once again on the Flash, on the html document, or until I enter "tab mode" by pressing tab! It's like the focus is nor on Flash, nor on Javascript. Although I guess the focus should somehow still be on Flash, otherwise how could it enter "tab mode"?

Do you have any insight what the problem might be?
Thanks in advance.

PS: please tell me if my explanations are unclear.

Comment: Ok my problem seems similar to the one posted here, I think his solution will work for me as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789771/flash-flex-sdk-as3-how-to-keep-keyboard-focus

Comment: I confirm it's working flawlessly \o/